# Twitter Extraction: Special Characters

Tags: java, twitter, tweets

I am trying to extract all tweets of some users for my research. 
But the special characters are being replaced with '?' symbol. How do I overcome this?

Example:

If the tweet is,

"If ωe give ɑ little love , maybe ωe can change the ωorld."

It gets stored as

"If ?e give ? little love , maybe ?e can change the ?orld."

Any idea how to fix this?

UPDATE:

I was handling it wrongly. So I changed the code to handle UTF-8 format.

PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");

out.println(rl_tweets);

Now It prints as

"If Ï‰e give É‘ little love , maybe Ï‰e can change the Ï‰orld."

Comment: It seems that you ωant to play ɑround with the encoding.

Comment: That's the lowercase version of the Greek letter omega (Ω).  [This may help.](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3a9/index.htm)

Answer (score 0):

There are special ways to encode every one of those letters in websites so that browsers understand which character to print on screen.
You may have to parse the code and change the characters to something the program you're using to display it understands (since not all programs understand that kind of encoding, which seems to be your problem).
So, for example, you could make a parser that changes something like *`&ntilde;`* which corresponds to a *ñ* in html to its particular encoding for that character.
You can find a list of html codes for strange characters here:
http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

That's what I did when I had to program a crawler and parse webpages.
I hope this helps.

-Daniel.

Comment: The problem is, I do not have control over it. Twitter API does the parsing and gives me back the result in this manner. So all I now have is a "?" character. I cannot convert it to anything. I use getUserTimeline to extract it

Answer (score 0):

What program are you using to get the data?

Let's take a look at a Tweet which contains those characters - https://twitter.com/edent/status/473752539289366528

If we call the API `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/show/473752539289366528.json`

We get this as a response (truncated)....

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

content-type: application/json;charset=utf-8
status: 200 OK

{
  "created_at": "Tue Jun 03 09:06:21 +0000 2014",
  "id": 473752539289366500,
  "id_str": "473752539289366528",
  "text": "@test If ωe give ɑ little love , maybe ωe can change the ωorld.",
  ....
```

As you can see, the API *does* pass through special characters.  It passes them through as UTF-8.  You need to make sure that you code is expecting - and can manipulate - Unicode Strings.

Comment: As you had mentioned, I was handling it wrong. But now even after handling it as UTF-8, I still get incorrect results.

Comment: What results do you see now?

Comment: I have updated the question with the updated results